# PostgreSQL INSERT on conflict, insert again only if any value is different

Tags: postgresql

I understand how to use PostgreSQL's `INSERT ON CONFLICT` to upsert or do nothing. However, I would like to achieve the behavior where if specified data values in the row are the same then do nothing, but if there is a difference insert a new row as opposed to updating an existing row.

For example, let's say you have a table called `test`:

```
create table test (id text, data text, created_on date);
```

```
INSERT INTO public.test (id, data, created_on)
  VALUES (1, 'foo', '2023-03-27'::date);
```

Then let's say we try to insert another row:

```
(1, 'foo', '2023-03-28'::date)
```

In this case, because `id` and `data` are the same then ignore it.

However, let's say we try to insert another row

```
(1, 'bar', '2023-03-28'::date)
```

Now, the value of data has changed, but instead of updating the original row, I want to insert a new row so:

```
select * from test
```

should yield

```
 id | data | created_on
----+------------------
 1  | foo  | 2023-03-27
 2  | foo  | 2023-03-28
```

Comment: Create a `unique key` on all columns and use that constraint for the `on conflict` clause.

Comment: Shouldn't the second row be `2, bar, 2023-03-28`?

Comment: sunde like you want `insert` ... `on conflict` ... `do nothing`

Comment: Make your case clear, please. There is no unique index defined. Show your UPSERT statement, even if it's not working (completely).

Comment: There can't be any conflict in your table, there is no unique constraint, not even a primary key. Without a conflict, ON CONFLICT will never happen.

Comment: In the title of the question you say "*if any value [in the row] is different*", but in the example you give you say "*because `id` and `data` are the same then ignore it*". So do you want to check only the `id` and `data` and ignore `created_on`, or do you really want to check all columns for differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `UNIQUE` constraint on the columns that you want to check for conflicts. In your case, that would appear to be

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id text,
  data text,
  created_on date,
  UNIQUE(id, data)
);
```

Then name those columns in the `ON CONFLICT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO public.test (id, data, created_on)
VALUES (1, 'foo', '2023-03-27'::date)
ON CONFLICT (id, data)
DO NOTHING;
```